Are PDDL and classical planners (e.g. FF) used in industry or consumer products?
I am learning classical planning techniques, and I know many examples of robots are in books. However, I am more curious about the real-world usage of these techniques.
Are PDDL and classical planners (e.g. FF) directly used in industry or consumer products? Or does every company or organization have its own representation of problems rather than directly using PDDL as representation language?
